# Visualize the lens space $L(1,1)\cong S^3$

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I know $L(p,q)\cong L(p,q-np)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so in particular $L(1,1)\cong L(1,0)\cong S^3$. It is easy to visualize $L(1,0)\cong S^3$ since the complement of an unknotted solid torus in $S^3$ is also a solid torus, and $L(1,0)$ is obtained by glueing the meridian of the fomer one with the longitude of the later one. My question is how to visualize $L(1,1)\cong S^3$. More generally, how to visualize $L(1,q)\cong S^3$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $L(p, q)$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, remove an unknotted solid torus, and glue another solid torus back such that the meridian of the new torus is isotopic to the p/q-curve of the old one. For $L(1,0)$, we remove a solid torus and glue a solid torus in the same way, so nothing changes. How about $L(1,1)$?

Comment: I see, it is less clear using this definition. If you use the definition $S^3/\sim$ where $(z_1, z_2) \sim (e^{2\pi i/p}z_1, e^{2\pi iq/p}z_2)$, then it is immediate.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese It seems that showing the two definitions are equivalent can answer my question. I know the standard way is to take a 3-ball, and divide it into the core (one solid torus) and its complement (the other solid torus), then twist them and glue them (https://services.phaidra.univie.ac.at/api/object/o:1323365/get page 40 for example). It seems work for $L(p,q)$, but I found it's hard to imagine it for $L(1,1)$. The 3-ball is acted by the trivial group. We can only get $L(1,0)$ instead of $L(1,1)$. Although they are homeomorphic, the constructions in my definition are different.